# Как удалить обработчик события после того, как событие произошло?

Tags: javascript

В [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) прочел следующее:

> Удаление EventListener из EventTarget не произойдет, если оно вызывается во время выполнения удаляемого события.

Проблема очевидна: я не знаю, когда произойдет событие. Но, тем не менее, когда оно произойдет, мне нужно обработчик как-то удалить.

То есть нечто подобное не срабатывает:

```
var func = function(event) {
    // ...
    el.removeEventListener("event", func);
};

el.addEventListener("event", func);
```

А если сделать так:

```
el.addEventListener("event", func);
el.removeEventListener("event", func);
```

то, очевидно, обработчик удалится сразу после того, как был навешен. Соответственно, и событие отловить не удастся.

Собственно, интересует "workaround". Была идея реализовать некий "after-filter", который бы выполнялся каждый раз после выполнения callback'а, но тогда этот "after-filter" сам станет частью этого же callback'а, что значит, что удаление обработчика не произойдет.

По поводу самостоятельного поиска решений.
Искал. Наткнулся на [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3723962/5899212) ответ. Почему он должен работать - не понимаю, ведь он противоречит словам MDN. Аналогичная ситуация [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26617886/5899212).

Comment: Русский перевод кривой. Нормально всё удаляется из обработчика события

Comment: всё работает https://jsfiddle.net/pkfqd1a1/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у вас в примере - да. У меня - нет. А из этого следует, что, как подсказал автор комментария выше, в MDN написана брехня, а я со своей стороны просто что-то упускаю. Но в целом спасибо за пример, теперь убедился, что ошибка с моей стороны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Добавил свой ответ с примерами кода в связи с увеличившимся количеством просмотров вопроса.*

---

На самом деле все прекрасно работает. Просто на MDN неправильно переведен английский оригинал.

```js
function handleClick(event) {
    console.log("Событие обработано");
    target.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
};

let target = document.querySelector("#target");
target.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

```css
#target {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">Нажми на меня</div>
```

Кроме того заставить обработчик отработать только один раз можно также передав методу `addEventListener` третьим параметром объект опций, содержащий `once: true`.

```js
function handleClick(event) {
    console.log("Событие обработано");
    // target.removeEventListener("click", handleClick); // Явно удалять обработчик больше нет необходимости
};

let target = document.querySelector("#target");
target.addEventListener("click", handleClick, {once: true}); // Обратите внимание на {once: true}
```

```css
#target {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">Нажми на меня</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вы не совсем поняли написанное.
Обработчик не удалится во время выполнения события - это так... но когда вы его удаляете в обработчике этого события, то событие уже произошло, и поэтому, проблемы с удалением быть не должно.

Comment: Не думаю. Скорее это неправильно перевод написан. А точнее, написана отсебятина, потому что в оригинале об этом вообще ничего не сказано. Тем более, если событие в обработчике считается уже произошедшим, то как тогда вообще получить доступ к событию во время его выполнения? Никак. В общем, дело в кривом переводе.

Comment: @smellyshovel
Не люблю вступать в дискуссии, но по первому пункту, [в оригинале](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) такой-же нотайс.

Comment: @smellyshovel
А в документе [DOM Living Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-eventtarget-removeeventlistener) Сказанно:
_An Event object is simply named an event
. It allows for signaling that something has occurred, e.g., that an image has completed downloading._
Что и говорит о том, что событие, это как бы не событие, а сигнал о событии. Но, а дальше уже включаются обработчики этого сигала, синтетические (навешанные разработчиком) и дефолтные (прописанные браузером), при этом навешенные обрабатываются в первую очередь, что позволяет прервать те, что по умолчанию.

Comment: @smellyshovel
Вы знаете, наверное соглашусь с несовсем удачным переводом, смысл бы лучше передался так: _Если использовать удаление слушателя события из уже навешанного обработчика, то обработчик все равно выполнится один раз (то есть не прервется), а в последствии уже выолняться не будет._

Comment: об этом и говорю

Comment: Если вас устроит Jquery то есть такой вариант  https://jquery-docs.ru/one/